# side menu item with [routerLink] results to navigating to the default route after double clicking

Tags: angular, routes, angular13

I'm resolving some bug on the side menu on an Angular application, when I click on the side menu item twice I'm always redirected to the default route. As shown from the screenshot below when I click on the `Financial years` menu item I will be redirected to the `Payment Account` route. What might be causing this behavior?

I'm using `routerLink` on the sidemenu Items.

[image]

As you can see below I'm using `routerLink`

```
...
<div class="category-children" *ngIf="rlaAcc.isActive">
    <!-- Section Bank Accounts -->
    <div mat-list-item id="item-accounting-transfers" data-intercom-target="Accounting module transfers"
      [routerLink]="['/accounting', property.id, 'transfers']" routerLinkActive="active-child"
      #rlaAccBank="routerLinkActive" class="child-header">
    </div>
    <div class="category-children" *ngIf="rlaAccBank.isActive">
      <div mat-list-item id="item-accounting-transfers" data-intercom-target="Accounting module transfers"
        [routerLink]="['/accounting', property.id, 'transfers', 'currents']" routerLinkActive="active-sub-child"
        class="child-header">

      </div>
      <div mat-list-item id="item-accounting-transfers" data-intercom-target="Accounting module transfers"
        [routerLink]="['/accounting', property.id, 'transfers', 'savings']" routerLinkActive="active-sub-child"
        class="child-header">
 
      </div>
    </div>
...
```

**Accounting ROUTES**

```
    export const ACCOUNTING_ROUTES: Route[] = [
       ....
      // Default link
      { 
        path: ':propId',
        redirectTo: '/accounting/:propId/transfers/currents',
        pathMatch: 'full', data:{propId:[`:propId`]},
        canActivate: [IsOnboardedGuard]
      },
      { path: ':propId/financial-years', loadChildren: () => import('@xyz/features/accounting/financial-years/main').then(m => m.FinancialYearsHomeModule), canActivate: [IsOnboardedGuard] },
   
     ......
    
    ];
```

**Financial Year ROUTES**

```
const FINANCIAL_YEAR_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FinancialYearsHomePage,
    children: [
      { path:'', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'overview', component: FYearsOverviewPage }
    ],
  },

];
```

**Route Logs from my test environment**

[image]

Comment: If you enter the `:propId/financial-years` route in address bar does it work? Does it work with single click or is double click the problem?

Comment: @Drenai when I click on the financial years side menu item  I'm able to navigate successfully to `http://localhost:4200/accounting/{{propId}}/financial-years/overview`. But when I click back again the side menu item `financial years`. I'm redirected to `http://localhost:4200/accounting/{{propId}}/transfers/currents`. The same behavior will persist if I  click on the side menu item twice. To answer your question if I enter the `:propId/financial-years` the link redirects to route `http://localhost:4200/accounting/{{propId}}/financial-years/overview`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was the routed component could not reload on the same url. In order to reload routed components on same url navigation, I set **onSameUrlNavigation** to **reload** and provide a [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) which returns **false** for shouldReuseRoute on the component.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private _router: Router){}

ngOnInit()
  {
    this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
  }
```